# How to i checkin to a facebook page?

Tags: facebook

I created a facebook page with a valid address for a physical place. Is there  way to have people checkin to this page using the checkin api/app?

Answer (score 0):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/checkin/
`'place=PAGE_ID'` sounds like it should be possible, but I don't think it is. You should just try it.

Now, let's evaluate **the better way**:
You have to create a new Place with your phone and merge it with your Page.
See this tutorial: http://www.allfacebook.com/facebook-places-business-2010-08
You can then checkin to this place like any other place with the Facebook-App or the API.